# Coding style best for performance

Tags: java, android

One situation, three different approaches.

**One** (variables are declared at the top of the activity as private):

```
radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.RadioGroup);

radioButton1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.RadioButton1);
radioButton2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.RadioButton2);

radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        if (radioButton1.isChecked()) {
            // do something
        } else if (radioButton2.isChecked()) {
            // do something
        }
    }
});
```

**Two:**

```
final RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.RadioGroup);

final RadioButton radioButton1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.RadioButton1);
final RadioButton radioButton2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.RadioButton2);

radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        if (radioButton1.isChecked()) {
            // do something
        } else if (radioButton2.isChecked()) {
            // do something
        }
    }
});
```

**Three:**

```
((RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.RadioGroup)).setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        if (((RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.RadioButton1)).isChecked()) {
            // do something
        } else if (((RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.RadioButton2)).isChecked()) {
            // do something
        }
    }
});
```

Which one is the "best" approach or it doesn't mind?

Comment: Why don't you use the checkedId parameter instead of if...else over each RadioButton instances?

Comment: CheckID paremeter? I guess I don't use because I don't know it. :D

Comment: public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) - the last param.

Comment: FYI, Java convention is to start instance variables with a lower case.

Comment: @johncarl I know, it's not real code. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is any difference between one and two. Three however, will suffer a performance penalty, because every time `onCheckedChanged` is fired, it will have to call `findViewById` for each radio button. The other methods are "caching" a reference to the `RadioButton`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Thats what I thougth, too.

Answer (score 1):

I think using 'one' would be the best way way, because private is usually treated like final when compiled. Secondly the access settings for final and private are the same.